# Python script to retrieve remote OS information without using nmap

Tags: nmap

I am trying to write a python script that can retrieve remote OS information (username, OS name, version, etc), like Nmap. Is it possible to do so without using Nmap ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible but consider this, nmap guess OS type and version by checking remote system response and compare it with its signature database and it is not accurate.